# FindFirstVolume does not return EFI system partition

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, disk, uefi

I am using FindFirstVolume/FindNextVolume to get a list of all volumes on a machine. That works well enough, but strangely the EFI system partition is skipped for some reason. Diskpart, on the other hand, returns the EFI system partition and the Disk Management UI shows it, too.

Here is diskpart's output:

```
DISKPART> list volume

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  Volume 0     C                NTFS   Partition    476 GB  Healthy    Boot
  Volume 1         Recovery     NTFS   Partition    450 MB  Healthy    Hidden
  Volume 2                      FAT32  Partition    100 MB  Healthy    System
  Volume 3     D   Data         NTFS   Partition    953 GB  Healthy
  Volume 4     E   ESD-USB      FAT32  Removable     14 GB  Healthy
```

In that list the EFI system partition is Volume 2.

FindFirstVolume/FindNextVolume give me the other four volumes, but omit the EFI system partition.

**Any ideas how I can get a volume GUID path for the EFI system parition or some other way to programmatically access it?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35102053/how-can-i-get-volume-name-for-efi-system-partition/35105012 may give you some idea

Comment: Are you running with elevated privileges?  I don't know exactly how Windows protects the EFI partition from unprivileged users, but it might result in the volume being skipped over when enumerating.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Yes, even as local system

Comment: @HarryJohnston I found a description for the partition attribute GPT_BASIC_DATA_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN. According to MSDN partitions with that attribute are ignored by FindFirstVolume. The EFI system partition does not have the hidden attribute set, but obviously the same is true.
Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365449(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: It would make sense for the system partition to be treated as if the hidden flag is set, so that, e.g., it isn't automatically mounted.  I think that explains it.

Comment: Find*Volume internal send `IOCTL_MOUNTMGR_QUERY_POINTS` to mountmgr MOUNTMGR_DEVICE_NAME - as result listed only mounted volumes. EFI or RAW volumes(partitions) usually not mounted - so not in mountmgr list. and this not related to thread privileges

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**volume GUID path** (i.e. \??\Volume{..}) not exist if not returned by `FindFirstVolume`/`FindNextVolume` but we can enumerate all volumes in system by different ways. we say can use [Virtual Disk Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb986750(v=vs.85).aspx) com api . `DISKPART> list volume` use exactly this. another way(more 'low' and fast) - use [CM_Get_Device_ID_ListW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff538415%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) with pszFilter = "{71a27cdd-812a-11d0-bec7-08002be2092f}" (look `GUID_DEVCLASS_VOLUME` in `devguid.h`) than obtain a device instance handle by [CM_Locate_DevNodeW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff538742(v=vs.85).aspx) and query for [DEVPKEY_Device_PDOName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff542580%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) with [CM_Get_DevNode_PropertyW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh780220%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) - we got string (like `\Device\HarddiskVolume<X>` ) which we can use in [ZwOpenFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567011(v=vs.85).aspx) and then use some ioctls (IOCTL_DISK_GET_PARTITION_INFO_EX and other) for get volume properties. code example:

```
#include <initguid.h>
#include <cfgmgr32.h>
#include <devguid.h>
#include <devpkey.h>
#include <diskguid.h>

void DumpVolume(HANDLE hFile);

void VolEnum()
{
    STATIC_WSTRING(DEVCLASS_VOLUME, "{71a27cdd-812a-11d0-bec7-08002be2092f}");

    enum { flags = CM_GETIDLIST_FILTER_CLASS|CM_GETIDLIST_FILTER_PRESENT };

    ULONG len;
    ULONG cb = 0, rcb = 64;

    HANDLE hFile;
    IO_STATUS_BLOCK iosb;
    UNICODE_STRING ObjectName;
    OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES oa = { sizeof(oa), 0, &ObjectName, OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE };

    if (!CM_Get_Device_ID_List_SizeW(&len, DEVCLASS_VOLUME, flags))
    {
        PWSTR buf = (PWSTR)alloca(len << 1);
        if (!CM_Get_Device_ID_ListW(DEVCLASS_VOLUME, buf, len, flags))
        {
            PVOID stack = buf;
            while (*buf)
            {
                DbgPrint("%S\n", buf);
                DEVINST dnDevInst;
                if (!CM_Locate_DevNodeW(&dnDevInst, buf, CM_LOCATE_DEVNODE_NORMAL))
                {
                    DEVPROPTYPE PropertyType;
                    int err;

                    union {
                        PVOID pv;
                        PWSTR sz;
                        PBYTE pb;
                    };

                    do 
                    {
                        if (cb < rcb)
                        {
                            rcb = cb = RtlPointerToOffset(pv = alloca(rcb - cb), stack);
                        }

                        if (!(err = CM_Get_DevNode_PropertyW(dnDevInst, &DEVPKEY_Device_PDOName, &PropertyType, pb, &rcb, 0)))
                        {
                            if (PropertyType == DEVPROP_TYPE_STRING)
                            {
                                DbgPrint("%S\n", sz);

                                RtlInitUnicodeString(&ObjectName, sz);
                                if (0 <= ZwOpenFile(&hFile, FILE_GENERIC_READ, &oa, &iosb, FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS, 0))
                                {
                                    DumpVolume(hFile);
                                    ZwClose(hFile);
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    } while (err == CR_BUFFER_SMALL);

                }
                buf += 1 + wcslen(buf);
            }
        }
    }
}

void DumpVolume(HANDLE hFile)
{
    NTSTATUS status;
    PARTITION_INFORMATION_EX pi;
    IO_STATUS_BLOCK iosb;

    if (0 <= (status = ZwDeviceIoControlFile(hFile, 0, 0, 0, &iosb, IOCTL_DISK_GET_PARTITION_INFO_EX, 0, 0, &pi, sizeof(pi))))
    {
        CHAR PartitionName[40], *szPartitionName;

        PCSTR szps = "??";
        switch (pi.PartitionStyle)
        {
        case PARTITION_STYLE_MBR: szps = "MBR";
            break;
        case PARTITION_STYLE_GPT: szps = "GPT";
            break;
        }

        DbgPrint("%u %s %I64u(%I64x) %I64u ", 
            pi.PartitionNumber, 
            szps, 
            pi.StartingOffset.QuadPart, pi.StartingOffset.QuadPart, 
            pi.PartitionLength.QuadPart);

        switch (pi.PartitionStyle)
        {

        case PARTITION_STYLE_MBR: 
            DbgPrint("type=%x boot=%x", pi.Mbr.PartitionType, pi.Mbr.BootIndicator);
            break;

        case PARTITION_STYLE_GPT:

            if (IsEqualGUID(pi.Gpt.PartitionType, PARTITION_ENTRY_UNUSED_GUID))
            {
                szPartitionName = "UNUSED";
            }
            else if (IsEqualGUID(pi.Gpt.PartitionType, PARTITION_SYSTEM_GUID))
            {
                szPartitionName = "SYSTEM";
            }
            else if (IsEqualGUID(pi.Gpt.PartitionType, PARTITION_MSFT_RESERVED_GUID))
            {
                szPartitionName = "RESERVED";
            }
            else if (IsEqualGUID(pi.Gpt.PartitionType, PARTITION_BASIC_DATA_GUID))
            {
                szPartitionName = "DATA";
            }
            else if (IsEqualGUID(pi.Gpt.PartitionType, PARTITION_MSFT_RECOVERY_GUID))
            {
                szPartitionName = "RECOVERY";
            }
            else if (IsEqualGUID(pi.Gpt.PartitionType, PARTITION_MSFT_SNAPSHOT_GUID))
            {
                szPartitionName = "SNAPSHOT";
            }
            else
            {
                sprintf(szPartitionName = PartitionName, "{%08x-%04x-%04x-%02x%02x-%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x}", 
                    pi.Gpt.PartitionType.Data1,
                    pi.Gpt.PartitionType.Data2,
                    pi.Gpt.PartitionType.Data3,
                    pi.Gpt.PartitionType.Data4[0],
                    pi.Gpt.PartitionType.Data4[1],
                    pi.Gpt.PartitionType.Data4[2],
                    pi.Gpt.PartitionType.Data4[3],
                    pi.Gpt.PartitionType.Data4[4],
                    pi.Gpt.PartitionType.Data4[5],
                    pi.Gpt.PartitionType.Data4[6],
                    pi.Gpt.PartitionType.Data4[7]);
            }
            DbgPrint("[%s] %I64x \"%S\"", 
                szPartitionName,
                pi.Gpt.Attributes,
                pi.Gpt.Name);
            break;
        }

        ULONG cb = FIELD_OFFSET(FILE_FS_ATTRIBUTE_INFORMATION, FileSystemName[32]);
        PFILE_FS_ATTRIBUTE_INFORMATION pffai = (PFILE_FS_ATTRIBUTE_INFORMATION)alloca(cb);

        switch (ZwQueryVolumeInformationFile(hFile, &iosb, pffai, cb, FileFsAttributeInformation))
        {
        case STATUS_SUCCESS:
        case STATUS_BUFFER_OVERFLOW:
            DbgPrint(" \"%.*S\"", pffai->FileSystemNameLength >> 1 , pffai->FileSystemName);
            break;
        }

        DbgPrint("\n");
    }
    else
    {
        DbgPrint("status=%x\n", status);
    }
}
```

and debug output

```
STORAGE\Volume\{d2bfdb30-4d04-11e5-824e-806e6f6e6963}#0000000012D00000
\Device\HarddiskVolume2
2 GPT 315621376(12d00000) 104857600 [SYSTEM] 8000000000000000 "EFI system partition" "FAT32"
STORAGE\Volume\{d2bfdb30-4d04-11e5-824e-806e6f6e6963}#0000000000100000
\Device\HarddiskVolume1
1 GPT 1048576(100000) 314572800 [RECOVERY] 8000000000000001 "Basic data partition" "NTFS"
STORAGE\Volume\{d2bfdb30-4d04-11e5-824e-806e6f6e6963}#0000000021100000
\Device\HarddiskVolume4
4 GPT 554696704(21100000) 255506513920 [DATA] 0 "Basic data partition" "NTFS"
STORAGE\Volume\{d2bfdb30-4d04-11e5-824e-806e6f6e6963}#0000000019100000
\Device\HarddiskVolume3
3 GPT 420478976(19100000) 134217728 [RESERVED] 8000000000000000 "Microsoft reserved partition" "RAW"
STORAGE\Volume\{a4d55aa5-4d7f-11e5-8256-5cc5d4ea6270}#0000000000007E00
\Device\HarddiskVolume5
1 MBR 32256(7e00) 32017013248 type=7 boot=1 "NTFS"
```

for attributes look - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365449(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Very useful, thank you so much!
Apparently the CM_* functions are the only ones that return the EFI system partition (and also RAW partitions). The SetupDi* functions don't do that (I checked).

Comment: This is working. But path to ESP can also be retrieved with much less code using ZwQuerySystemInformation and SystemSystemPartitionInformation (0x62) info class.