# Windows Wdk: When i try to add Windows.h and Wdm.h, re-definition error is coming between ntdef.h and winnt.h

Tags: windows

I am trying to find EFI partition using `CM_Get_Device_ID_ListW()`, `CM_Get_DevNode_PropertyW()`, and `ZwDeviceIoControlFile()` Windows API. This is a shell application only. I used `stdio` to print on terminal. Below is the order of adding all header files. I tried to include following files:

```
#include <WINDOWS.h>
#include <initguid.h>
#include <devguid.h>
#include <devpkey.h>
#include <diskguid.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cfgmgr32.h>
#include <Wdm.h>
```

I am using Windows 7, 64-bit, Visual Studio 2010. In VS2010 I set the include path:

```
F:\Programs\WINDDK\7600.16385.1\inc;F:\Programs\WINDDK\7600.16385.1\inc\api;F:\Programs\WINDDK\7600.16385.1\inc\crt;F:\Programs\WINDDK\7600.16385.1\inc\ddk;
```

Lib path:

```
F:\Programs\WINDDK\7600.16385.1\lib\win7\i386\
```

I get Compile Errors like:

```
f:\programs\winddk\7600.16385.1\inc\api\ntdef.h(128): warning C4005: 'MAX_NATURAL_ALIGNMENT' : macro redefinition
f:\programs\winddk\7600.16385.1\inc\api\winnt.h(109) : see previous definition of 'MAX_NATURAL_ALIGNMENT'
f:\programs\winddk\7600.16385.1\inc\api\ntdef.h(161): warning C4005: 'PROBE_ALIGNMENT' : macro redefinition
f:\programs\winddk\7600.16385.1\inc\api\winnt.h(142) : see previous definition of 'PROBE_ALIGNMENT'
f:\programs\winddk\7600.16385.1\inc\api\ntdef.h(614): error C2011: '_PROCESSOR_NUMBER' : 'struct' type redefinition
f:\programs\winddk\7600.16385.1\inc\api\winnt.h(493) : see declaration of '_PROCESSOR_NUMBER'
f:\programs\winddk\7600.16385.1\inc\api\ntdef.h(625): error C2011: '_GROUP_AFFINITY' : 'struct' type redefinition
f:\programs\winddk\7600.16385.1\inc\api\winnt.h(504) : see declaration of '_GROUP_AFFINITY'
f:\programs\winddk\7600.16385.1\inc\api\ntdef.h(882): error C2011: '_FLOAT128' : 'struct' type redefinition
f:\programs\winddk\7600.16385.1\inc\api\winnt.h(630) : see declaration of '_FLOAT128'
f:\programs\winddk\7600.16385.1\inc\api\ntdef.h(933): error C2011: '_LARGE_INTEGER' : 'union' type redefinition
f:\programs\winddk\7600.16385.1\inc\api\winnt.h(677) : see declaration of '_LARGE_INTEGER'
f:\programs\winddk\7600.16385.1\inc\api\ntdef.h(951): error C2011: '_ULARGE_INTEGER' : 'union' type redefinition
f:\programs\winddk\7600.16385.1\inc\api\winnt.h(695) : see declaration of '_ULARGE_INTEGER'
f:\programs\winddk\7600.16385.1\inc\api\ntdef.h(973): error C2011: '_LUID' : 'struct' type redefinition
f:\programs\winddk\7600.16385.1\inc\api\winnt.h(717) : see declaration of '_LUID'
f:\programs\winddk\7600.16385.1\inc\api\ntdef.h(1070): error C2084: function 'ULONGLONG Int64ShllMod32(ULONGLONG,DWORD)' already has a body
f:\programs\winddk\7600.16385.1\inc\api\winnt.h(771) : see previous definition of 'Int64ShllMod32'
f:\programs\winddk\7600.16385.1\inc\api\ntdef.h(1086): error C2084: function 'LONGLONG Int64ShraMod32(LONGLONG,DWORD)' already has a body
f:\programs\winddk\7600.16385.1\inc\api\winnt.h(778) : see previous definition of 'Int64ShraMod32'
f:\programs\winddk\7600.16385.1\inc\api\ntdef.h(1102): error C2084: function 'ULONGLONG Int64ShrlMod32(ULONGLONG,DWORD)' already has a body
f:\programs\winddk\7600.16385.1\inc\api\winnt.h(785) : see previous definition of 'Int64ShrlMod32'
f:\programs\winddk\7600.16385.1\inc\api\ntdef.h(1318): warning C4005: 'UNICODE_STRING_MAX_BYTES' : macro redefinition
f:\programs\winddk\7600.16385.1\inc\api\winnt.h(957) : see previous definition of 'UNICODE_STRING_MAX_BYTES'
f:\programs\winddk\7600.16385.1\inc\api\ntdef.h(1358): error C2011: '_LIST_ENTRY' : 'struct' type redefinition
f:\programs\winddk\7600.16385.1\inc\api\winnt.h(966) : see declaration of '_LIST_ENTRY'....
```

Can anyone help to resolve this?

Comment: Improve formatting of commands and error messages. Improve grammar.

Comment: for `CM_*` api enouth include `Cfgmgr32.h`. instead `ZwDeviceIoControlFile` you can use `DeviceIoControl` - so formal you can not include `ntifs.h` or `wdm.h`. however if you want do this - include this header in **namespace** - like `namespace NT { #include <ntifs.h> };` this resolve almost all errors, but 3-4 compiler errors persist even after this. however it can be resolved, if little smart edit wdk headers. and if you include `ntifs.h` in namespace - include your code in the same namespace too - this let you not use prefix for all wdk functions, structs, enums..

Comment: and for get EFI partitions you can use `CM_Get_Device_Interface_ListW` with `GUID_DEVINTERFACE_HIDDEN_VOLUME`

Comment: `windows.h` is for user-mode applications, `wdm.h` is for kernel-mode device drivers.  They're mutually exclusive.  You can work around this, as RbMm has already explained, but the reason it doesn't work out of the box is that you're not supposed to be doing what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hi RbMm... i am using your  provided sample code  only...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40208794/findfirstvolume-does-not-return-efi-system-partition...thanks for input.